# Setting E-Shell Alias

Tags: eshell

In my emacs alias file located at *.emacs.d/eshell/alias*, I have the following:

`alias mv mv -v $*`

Whenever I execute the alias in eshell, for example: `mv from_here.txt to_here.text`, I get the error:

> mv: missing destination file or directory

How can this alias issue be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first a comment on your alias.
While [the emacswiki-page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias) suggests that `alias mv 'mv -v $*'` is right the [corresponding official manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Aliases.html) says that you should use `alias mv mv -v` instead.
In the following I assume that the manual page is right.

It looks like `eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias` is buggy (at least in emacs 25.2.1).

The current implementation is

```el
(defun eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias (command args)
  "If COMMAND has an alias definition, call that instead using ARGS."
  (unless (and eshell-prevent-alias-expansion
           (member command eshell-prevent-alias-expansion))
    (let ((alias (eshell-lookup-alias command)))
      (if alias
      (throw 'eshell-replace-command
         `(let ((eshell-command-name ',eshell-last-command-name)
                        (eshell-command-arguments ',eshell-last-arguments)
                        (eshell-prevent-alias-expansion
                         ',(cons command eshell-prevent-alias-expansion)))
                    ,(eshell-parse-command (nth 1 alias))))))))
```

The `throw` form replaces the command to be executed. In `eshell-parse-command` the alias is replaced but the arguments are lost.

My eshell shows the expected `alias` behavior if I add `args` to `eshell-parse-command` via the following override:

```el
(defun eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias-bugfix-25.2.1 (command args)
  "If COMMAND has an alias definition, call that instead using ARGS."
  (unless (and eshell-prevent-alias-expansion
           (member command eshell-prevent-alias-expansion))
    (let ((alias (eshell-lookup-alias command)))
      (if alias
      (throw 'eshell-replace-command
         `(let ((eshell-command-name ',eshell-last-command-name)
                        (eshell-command-arguments ',eshell-last-arguments)
                        (eshell-prevent-alias-expansion
                         ',(cons command eshell-prevent-alias-expansion)))
                    ,(eshell-parse-command (nth 1 alias) args)))))))

(advice-add #'eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias :override #'eshell-maybe-replace-by-alias-bugfix-25.2.1)
```

Note that I already sent [a bug-report to `bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-08/msg00143.html).

Thanks for fixing this problem in the master branch of emacs goes to Noam Postavsky:
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=e66e81679c3c91d6bf8f62c7abcd968430b4d1fe