# (set-eshell-alias!) for mv causes error: missing destination file or directory

Tags: eshell, aliases

In doom emacs, I'm setting some aliases in my config as follows:

```
(set-eshell-alias!
        "ls" "exa --icons $*"
        "doomsync" "~/.emacs.d/bin/doom sync"
        "rm" "rm -Iv $*"
        "mv" "mv -iv $*"
        "ps-sorted-by-cpu" "ps c -eo pid,user,command,%mem,%cpu --sort %cpu ; echo 'pid,user,command,%mem,%cpu'"
        "ps-sorted-by-mem" "ps c -eo pid,user,command,%mem,%cpu --sort %mem ; echo 'pid,user,command,%mem,%cpu'")
```

These mostly work fine, except mv. If I try to do that with my alias I get the following

```
~/Downloads/test λ mkdir a

~/Downloads/test λ touch b

~/Downloads/test λ ls
 a   b

~/Downloads/test λ mv b a
mv: missing destination file or directory
```

I noticed [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34652/setting-e-shell-alias) created on a very similar issue a few years ago, however that same thread notes that this had been fixed on the master branch of emacs, so I assume this is a different issue? Anyone know what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I dunno exactly why it's not working, but when I do...

`alias mv 'mv -iv $1 $2'`

...it works

Something must be up with how all the args are parsed. I'd file a bug report.